# facebook does not see my domain

Tags: facebook, url, dns

I've been having issues recently with setting up links between Facebook and a website I've developed - www.newcarpromotions.co.uk. After some digging around, and advise on this forum, Ive used the following link to see what Facebook thinks of my domain:-

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=newcarpromotions.co.uk

What it returns is as follows:-

"Error Parsing URL  Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped"

Now Ive tried all my other domains which return all the correct information as you would expect.

Has anyone seen this before? It looks like Facebook doesn't think my domain exists! If that's the case any idea how I can get this resolved?

Nick

Comment: I forgot to add the domain was registered for almost 12 months.

Answer (score 1):

According to this post ([Linter gives "Error parsing URL" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538596/linter-gives-error-parsing-url-error)) it seems that the facebook object debugger can return that error if it fails to parse your page somehow.  I'm suggesting that facebook can get to your website but is failing for a different reason.  You may want to look at your request logs to verify that facebook is hitting your site.

If worse comes to worse you can open a bug here: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/