# HTML 5 / Site config causing FB block

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, url, facebook-graph-api

I created a new website using a newly registered domain.

When trying to share it as a link in Facebook, it is classed as "spammy" and I'm unable to share it.

After a few weeks of research and reporting to FB I copied the site entirely and placed on a new `TLD`.

This has instantly become blocked on facebook which made me think there's something within the structure of the site which is causing it to be marked as spam.

Using object debugger on the original URL has given a number of various responses such as:

- "Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped"
- Response code 206
- Response code 203

I read that using `chrome` can bug it out so I used `firefox` and `safari` to check.

Does anyone have any idea why the response codes vary for a static site?

Are there any specific site setups which are currently causing FB to block?

I have read that certain `.htaccess` configs, such as www>non-www can upset FB, is this true?

The sites in question are:

[Link 1](http://www.sophiemcelligott.com) (this was intended to be the only domain)
[Link 2](http://www.sophiemcelligott.co.uk) (this was setup only when original domain was blocked)

These domain are new, never been used for spamming or mail.
I have checked all the blacklists I could possibly search and have not found anything that indicates problems.

It really does seem that there is something in the configuration of the site that is causing it to be blocked. Does anyone have any idea or experience in this??

Comment: Hi. Have you tried the suggested solutions here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538596/linter-gives-error-parsing-url-error

Comment: Hello martn. Yes, I was aware of that post and the suggested solutions. In regards to the facebook meta tags, I have removed them completely. This has had no effect, both sites are still blocked. I have also tried with and without a php redirect(simply by removing .htaccess files. After making each change I wait 13 hours before checking as I was told that the URL debugger forces a re-caching but only once every 12 hours. Not sure if this is correct but thought best to wait just in case.

Comment: I have absolutely no progress in trying to understand why these sites have been blocked or how to get them unblocked. I am planning to create a new url and use that as the primary domain but can anyone tell me if having it hosted on the same IP will cause it to be blocked aswell?

Comment: Similar issues here, did you make any progress?

Comment: It is now 1 year and 2 days (approximately) since I originally posted this issue. I still have no idea what caused the issue or how it can be rectified. I have tried asking for support in with both Facebook and even reported as a bug with in Facebook developers. The domain is still blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to scrape the page correctly using the Debug Lint tool:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sophie-mcelligott.com%2F

Maybe facebook block newly registered domains for a fixed time before letting you share it on Facebook, presumably to stop spammers. Are you able to scrape both sites correctly?

Comment: Niraj, that is a different domain.

Comment: That was the domain you provided in Link 1. Link 2 works for me too.

Comment: Link 1 & Link 2 are different domains to the one you originially linked, yours link has a "-". But anyway! Upon checking today the domains are working. I am not sure why they were blocked or how they have become unblocked after. Thanks for trying to help Niraj