# Facebook share parsing page error

Tags: facebook

On Facebook developer tool page we are getting parsing error
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
while accessing this url 
http://www.gooberdeals.com/frontindex/source/1727

I am getting the following error:

Error Parsing URL:  Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.

Answer (score 1):

Your pages are extremely slow, average response time is over 13-15 seconds.

I've noticed that if response time was under 9-10 seconds Linter returned correct results (with some warnings)...

[image: URL Linter response]

Try to reduce response time for your pages, it'll be good for all, load time matters and this is a key factor for users to consider returning to your site...

Answer (score 0):

You may find the answer here on [Linter gives "Error parsing URL" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538596/linter-gives-error-parsing-url-error)

This implies that the URL you are using actually is incorrect (or should I say, is being formed incorrectly).